# "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' Error coming while using dynamic field in django update query

Tags: django, django-views

user = models.users.objects.filter(token=request.POST['token'],otp=otp).update(Q(**{ column: new_email_or_phone}));

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is due to invalid data. The original error occurs when trying to convert string to integer line `int('s')` which can't be converted. So check your data in `request.POST`